# Placeholders application.properties file in a SpringBoot project

Tags: java

application.properties file in a SpringBoot project -

```
com.sde.abc.component.test.orgunitSingle.delete=/US-00000/orgUnits/${orgUnit}
```

I have injected it into my Java file as below -

```
@Value("${com.sde.abc.component.test.orgunitSingle.delete}")
private String url;
```

Now I need to replace "orgUnit" with some value in my function(i.e-dynamic). How do I get to do this or am I completely missing it? I want to fetch value from map and dynamically insert "orgUnit",what can be done??

Comment: where is ORGID ?

Comment: sorry its orgUnit,I have edited

Comment: If you need to replace some value in a String variable, you can use ``replace``, ``replaceAll`` or ``replaceFirst`` method of java.lang.String class.

Comment: As far as I get it, you're trying to construct a REST API path to delete a resource. You don't need to have the ${orgUnit} in application properties. When constructing the URL in your REST client: 1) get the API delete url from application.properties. 2) append the necessary ${orgUnit} value directly in code

Comment: Thanks it worked :)